# Session timeout is not working on main page when a popup is opened from that page

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, session, popup

I am developing a small spring MVC application. When user logged in successfully, a welcome page will be displayed and when session timedout it ll auto redirect to login page.
On welcome page I have a button, and onclick of button opens a popup window. Now after opening popup window if session timed out, my popup should close and parent page should redirect to login page.
I have tried something with meta tag like below on parent page and popup window.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<%=session.getMaxInactiveInterval()%>;url=login"/>
```

But it is not working. session is not getting timed out at all when popup is open. Page is auto refreshing, but session not getting expired even in parent page also.

Welcome Page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>  
<%@ page session="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<%=session.getMaxInactiveInterval()%>;url=login"/>

<title>Home page</title>
<script>
    function popup() {
        window.open("../Bank/register", 'window', 'width=200,height=100');
    }
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome ${sessionScope.USER_NAME}..!</h1>
    <c:if test="${sessionScope.USER_ROLE==1}">
        <!-- <a href="register">Register</a> -->
    <a href="#" onclick="popup()">Register</a>
    </c:if>
    <a href="logout">Logout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Popup page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<%=session.getMaxInactiveInterval()%>;url=login"/>
<title>Bank - Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form:form action="register" method="post" modelAttribute="register">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="username">User Name:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="username" name="username" id="username" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="fName">First Name:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="fName" name="fName" id="fName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="lName">Last Name:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="lName" name="lName" id="lName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="password">Password:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:password path="password" name="password" id="password"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="Email">Email:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="Email" name="Email" id="Email" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="phoneNo">Phone No:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="phoneNo" id="phoneNo" name="phoneNo"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="IsAdmin">Is Admin:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:checkbox path="IsAdmin"  id="IsAdmin" name="IsAdmin" value="1"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:button id="reset" name="reset" onClick="document.forms[0].reset();">Reset</form:button></td>
                <td><form:button id="register" name="register">Register</form:button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form:form>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-style: italic; color: red;">${Message}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

If I am not using popup window and use just URL redirect in seperate tab, it is working fine. But I had to use popup. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Usually session timeouts in a web application are handled via `web.xml`

You can include the following snippet in your web.xml and it will take care of the timeouts.

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>30</session-timeout><!-- in minutes -->
</session-config>
```

If you don't have a `web.xml` in your application, you can set the same `session-timeout` in your application container's `web.xml`

For example if your application container is tomcat you can find the web.xml at `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml` and you can define `session-timeout` in that file. The default value is `30 min` in case of tomcat.

No need to include the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<%=session.getMaxInactiveInterval()%>;url=login"/>` in all the jsp files.

Comment: I have already set session-timeout in my web.xml. And I have removed <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<%=session.getMaxInactiveInterval()%>;url=login"/> tag in pop up page and kept it only on home page. Still same issue is happening.